# Dynamically created row with onclick event using jquery selector not working

Tags: jquery

I have a table where users can add rows using jquery. This is all working fine to a point.
the problem I have is the dynamically created row has a button with an onclick event that opens a modal screen of which values are passed to the modal screen. The problem is I can't seem to get the jquery selector to work to return the value. The selector is:  $("#defect1_' + counter + '").val() , this errors out.
This works in the static lines but fails in the JS dynamically created line.
Any offerings of help will be much appreciated.

***UPDATED***
Full add row function with onclick events:
JS:

```
            $(".addrow").click(function(){

            counter = $('#myTable tr').length;
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";
            var hash = "#";
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" readonly="true" value="' + counter + '" id="row_id" class="form-control input-sm txtRowId"><input type="hidden" class="txtDefect1Selection" id="defect1Selection_' + counter + '" name="defect1Selection_' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" class="txtDefect2Selection" id="defect2Selection_' + counter + '" name="defect2Selection_' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" class="txtPh1" id="Ph1_' + counter + '" name="Ph1_' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm txtMaterial" id="material_id_' + counter + '" name="material_id_' + counter + '" style="width:150px" required></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm txtDescription" id="description_' + counter + '" name="description_' + counter + '" readonly="true" style="width:200px"><input type="hidden" readonly="true" class="txtPlant" id="plant_' + counter + '" name="plant_' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" readonly="true" class="form-control input-sm txtHierarchy" id="hierarchy_' + counter + '" name="hierarchy_' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="quantity_' + counter + '" name="quantity_' + counter + '" style="width:70px"><input type="hidden" value="quantity" id="quantityfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="bar_code_' + counter + '" name="bar_code_' + counter + '" style="width:150px"><input type="hidden" value="bar_code" id="barcodefixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="invoice_number_' + counter + '" name="invoice_number_' + counter + '" style="width:150px"><input type="hidden" value="invoice_number" id="invoicenumberfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="defect1_' + counter + '" name="defect1_' + counter + '" style="width:150px" readonly="true"><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm input-group-addon" id="defectsmodal1" onclick="openDefectsModal(' + counter + ',$('#defect1_' + counter).val(),$('#defect1Selection_' + counter).val(),$('#Ph1_' + counter).val(),$('#claim_id').val(),1);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></span></div></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="defect2_' + counter + '" name="defect2_' + counter + '" style="width:150px" readonly="true"><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm input-group-addon" id="defectsmodal2" onclick="openDefectsModal(' + counter + ',$('#defect2_' + counter).val(),$('#defect2Selection_' + counter).val(),$('#Ph1_' + counter).val(),$('#claim_id').val(),2);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></span></div></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" value="where_found" id="where_foundfixed_' + counter + '"><select name="where_found_' + counter + '" id="where_found_' + counter + '" style="height:30px" <option value="" selected></option><option value="1"><cfoutput>#textconstants.customer#</cfoutput></option><option value="2"><cfoutput>#textconstants.quality_control#</cfoutput></option></select></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" value="shipment" id="shipmentfixed_' + counter + '"><select name="shipment_' + counter + '" id="shipment_' + counter + '" style="height:30px"><option value="" selected></option><option value="1"><cfoutput>#textconstants.pallet#</cfoutput></option><option value="2"><cfoutput>#textconstants.post#</cfoutput></option><option value="3"><cfoutput>#textconstants.container#</cfoutput></option></select></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="remarks_' + counter + '" name="remarks_' + counter + '" ondblclick="openRemarksModal('+ counter +',$(this).val());"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" value="rework" id="reworkfixed_' + counter + '"><select name="rework_' + counter + '" id="rework_' + counter + '" style="height:30px"><option value="" selected></option><cfoutput><option value="1">#textconstants.no_rework#</option><option value="2">#textconstants.failed_rework#</option><option value="3">#textconstants.rework_ok#</option></cfoutput></select></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="addphotos(' + counter + ')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></button></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="product_installed_' + counter + '" id="product_installed_' + counter + '" style="height:30px; width:120px"></option><option value="TRUE"><cfoutput>#textconstants.yes#</cfoutput></option><option selected value="FALSE"><cfoutput>#textconstants.no#</cfoutput></option></select><input type="hidden" value="product_installed" id="productinstalledfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="request_' + counter + '" id="request_' + counter + '" style="height:30px; width:120px"><option value="" selected></option><option value="1"><cfoutput>#textconstants.credit_note#</cfoutput></option><option value="2"><cfoutput>#textconstants.replacement#</cfoutput></option><option value="3"><cfoutput>#textconstants.no_action#</cfoutput></option></select><input type="hidden" value="request" id="requestfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';

            newRow.append(cols);
            counter++;
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);

        });
```

Comment: can you post your JS?

Comment: @jmore009 Sorry don't follow, I have posted the dynamic row JS, what other JS do you require? The problem is around the onclick event in the posted code.

Comment: When you say it 'errors out', what is the error?

Comment: I see now, originally all I saw was HTML, can you recreate this in a fiddle? It's hard to do anything with what you posted

Comment: Please post a [small, stand-alone, repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) and the actual error message.

Comment: Not sure this should be tagged as Coldfusion - not seeing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

When you add new dynamic content and try to access it or its values, you should include in selector of the dynamic content the name of a static parent that contains the dynamic generated content.
Try to use **table** as the static parent.
example:

```
$("table #defect1_" + counter).val()
```

Updated answer according to question new text:

```
$(".addrow").click(function(){
                console.log('a');
                counter = $('#myTable tr').length;
                var newRow = $("<tr>");
                var cols = "";
                var hash = "#";
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" readonly="true" value="' + counter + '" id="row_id" class="form-control input-sm txtRowId"><input type="hidden" class="txtDefect1Selection" id="defect1Selection_' + counter + '" name="defect1Selection_' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" class="txtDefect2Selection" id="defect2Selection_' + counter + '" name="defect2Selection_' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" class="txtPh1" id="Ph1_' + counter + '" name="Ph1_' + counter + '"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm txtMaterial" id="material_id_' + counter + '" name="material_id_' + counter + '" style="width:150px" required></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm txtDescription" id="description_' + counter + '" name="description_' + counter + '" readonly="true" style="width:200px"><input type="hidden" readonly="true" class="txtPlant" id="plant_' + counter + '" name="plant_' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" readonly="true" class="form-control input-sm txtHierarchy" id="hierarchy_' + counter + '" name="hierarchy_' + counter + '"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="quantity_' + counter + '" name="quantity_' + counter + '" style="width:70px"><input type="hidden" value="quantity" id="quantityfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="bar_code_' + counter + '" name="bar_code_' + counter + '" style="width:150px"><input type="hidden" value="bar_code" id="barcodefixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="invoice_number_' + counter + '" name="invoice_number_' + counter + '" style="width:150px"><input type="hidden" value="invoice_number" id="invoicenumberfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="defect1_' + counter + '" name="defect1_' + counter + '" style="width:150px" readonly="true"><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm input-group-addon" id="defectsmodal1" onclick="openDefectsModal(' + counter + ','+$('#defect1_' + counter).val() +', '+ $('#defect1Selection_' + counter).val() +','+$('#Ph1_' + counter).val()+','+$('#claim_id').val()+',+1);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></span></div></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="defect2_' + counter + '" name="defect2_' + counter + '" style="width:150px" readonly="true"><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm input-group-addon" id="defectsmodal2" onclick="openDefectsModal(' + counter + ', '+$('#defect2_' + counter).val()+','+$('#defect2Selection_' + counter).val()+','+$('#Ph1_' + counter).val()+','+$('#claim_id').val()+',2);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></span></div></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" value="where_found" id="where_foundfixed_' + counter + '"><select name="where_found_' + counter + '" id="where_found_' + counter + '" style="height:30px" <option value="" selected></option><option value="1"><cfoutput>#textconstants.customer#</cfoutput></option><option value="2"><cfoutput>#textconstants.quality_control#</cfoutput></option></select></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" value="shipment" id="shipmentfixed_' + counter + '"><select name="shipment_' + counter + '" id="shipment_' + counter + '" style="height:30px"><option value="" selected></option><option value="1"><cfoutput>#textconstants.pallet#</cfoutput></option><option value="2"><cfoutput>#textconstants.post#</cfoutput></option><option value="3"><cfoutput>#textconstants.container#</cfoutput></option></select></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="remarks_' + counter + '" name="remarks_' + counter + '" ondblclick="openRemarksModal('+ counter +',$(this).val());"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><input type="hidden" value="rework" id="reworkfixed_' + counter + '"><select name="rework_' + counter + '" id="rework_' + counter + '" style="height:30px"><option value="" selected></option><cfoutput><option value="1">#textconstants.no_rework#</option><option value="2">#textconstants.failed_rework#</option><option value="3">#textconstants.rework_ok#</option></cfoutput></select></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="addphotos(' + counter + ')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></button></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="product_installed_' + counter + '" id="product_installed_' + counter + '" style="height:30px; width:120px"></option><option value="TRUE"><cfoutput>#textconstants.yes#</cfoutput></option><option selected value="FALSE"><cfoutput>#textconstants.no#</cfoutput></option></select><input type="hidden" value="product_installed" id="productinstalledfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';
                cols += '<td row-id="' + counter + '"><select name="request_' + counter + '" id="request_' + counter + '" style="height:30px; width:120px"><option value="" selected></option><option value="1"><cfoutput>#textconstants.credit_note#</cfoutput></option><option value="2"><cfoutput>#textconstants.replacement#</cfoutput></option><option value="3"><cfoutput>#textconstants.no_action#</cfoutput></option></select><input type="hidden" value="request" id="requestfixed_' + counter + '"></td>';

                newRow.append(cols);
                counter++;
                $("table.order-list").append(newRow);

            });
```

You had some spelling wrong in your code. I fixed it here. P.S. Where are elements with id = "defect1_" declared ?

Comment: OP is using an `onclick` attribute, not attaching a handler through jQuery.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  The error i'm getting if the new dynamic row is the third row is; 'defect1_3' is undefined. This only errors in IE11. Works In Chrome and FF.

Comment: @JeepersCreepers are you sure that element exists? If the rows are zero based, the third row would be `defect1_2`.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yes it exists, this does work in FF.

Comment: @besciualex Your fiddle doesn't have the onclick events for each dynamic row. Please have a look at the full addrow function that I have now added, it might make things a little more clear on what im trying to do.